# How to support Feign in the html http request?

Tags: spring-cloud, feign

Feign now does load balancing using Eureka, now I want to invoke calls outside the Eureka system. 
For example, I want to invoke a url in a html request, how to use Feign to support load balancing anyway without using the nginx to forward?

Comment: Have you checked out the docs here yet? http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR2/#spring-cloud-feign